# Is it safe to remove xorg in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: xorg, 17.10

I upgrade a desktop machine from Ubuntu 16.04.3 to 17.04 and again 17.10.  Since Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland by default and `xorg` is kept back, is it safe to remove `xorg` at all? The following is what happens when I tried to `apt upgrade`, `apt install xorg` and `apt remove xorg`:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xorg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt install xorg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xorg : Depends: xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+19ubuntu3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt remove xorg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  x11-apps x11-session-utils xinit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop xorg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I notice that `ubuntu-desktop` will be removed along with `xorg`. Does it mean the whole desktop will be gone so that I can't remove `xorg` at all if I want to use the desktop?

Comment: Yes 17.10 uses xorg by default.  The current rumor is that 18.04 will use xorg by default, and there have been several reported errors and problems with some graphical applications which need xorg to run properly (gksudo, gparted and a few others).  You *could* remove xorg, but I think that the real question is "What would you gain from removing xorg?"

Comment: @CharlesGreen If you dont mind but 17.10 uses wayland by default. Only if the machine is unable to run wayland it switches to Xorg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove all of xorg. The `xorg` package is a mostly empty meta package, so removing only it will achieve no perceivable difference in normal operation of the system.

The session files for both the wayland and xorg sessions, are in the same package, as well, so you won't be able to get rid of the *Ubuntu (Xorg)* option from the login menu.